# Failed to start The PHP 8.0 FastCGI Process when update to php8.0

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to update from php7.4 to php8.0

I applied the following steps

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update

apt-get install php8.0 php8.0-bz2 php8.0-cgi php8.0-cli php8.0-common php8.0-curl php8.0-fpm php8.0-gd php8.0-intl php8.0-mbstring php8.0-mysql php8.0-opcache php8.0-pspell php8.0-readline php8.0-xml php8.0-zip php8.0-imagick
```

But I got the error

```
php8.0-fpm.service - The PHP 8.0 FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php8.0-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-03-25 19:49:43 +03; 10ms ago
     Docs: man:php-fpm8.0(8)
  Process: 6949 ExecStopPost=/usr/lib/php/php-fpm-socket-helper remove /run/php/php-fpm.sock /etc/php/8.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf 80 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6941 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm8.0 --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php/8.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf (code=exited, status=78)
 Main PID: 6941 (code=exited, status=78)


Mar 25 19:48:53 server.aaaaaa.com systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 8.0 FastCGI Process Manager...
Mar 25 19:48:53 server.aaaaaa.com php-fpm8.0[6224]: [25-Mar-2022 19:48:53] ERROR: failed to open configuration file '/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf': No such file or directory (2)
Mar 25 19:48:53 server.aaaaaa.com php-fpm8.0[6224]: [25-Mar-2022 19:48:53] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf'
Mar 25 19:48:53 server.aaaaaa.com php-fpm8.0[6224]: [25-Mar-2022 19:48:53] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
Mar 25 19:48:53 server.aaaaaa.com systemd[1]: php8.0-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
Mar 25 19:48:53 server.aaaaaa.com systemd[1]: php8.0-fpm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 25 19:48:53 server.aaaaaa.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP 8.0 FastCGI Process Manager.
dpkg: error processing package php8.0-fpm (--configure):
 installed php8.0-fpm package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php8.0-fpm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Knowing that there is no "php-fpm.conf" file in "/etc/php/8.0/fpm/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By logs I see somehow You've lost config file: `/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf`

So I found one in my server and put to Gist.

Need to put that on Your server.

In terminal:

```
cd ~

wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/num8er/6cf84e1a544cc7751d3f6974d10b10a0/raw/d9bf057d3acc297d79235b282319f29f60a4301b/php-fpm.conf

sudo mv php-fpm.conf /etc/php/8.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf

sudo systemctl restart php8.0-fpm
```

if You still have issues, uninstall all php stuff, and install again:

```
apt purge -y php7.4*

apt purge -y php8.0*

apt-get install php8.0 php8.0-fpm php8.0-dev php8.0-bz2 php8.0-cgi php8.0-cli php8.0-common php8.0-curl php8.0-gd php8.0-intl php8.0-mbstring php8.0-mysql php8.0-mysqli php8.0-pdo php8.0-opcache php8.0-pspell php8.0-readline php8.0-xml php8.0-zip php8.0-imagick
```

Comment: `systemctl stop php8.0-fpm; systemctl stop php7.4-fpm; systemctl start php8.0-fpm;`

Comment: add Your problem: `systemctl status php8.0-fpm` to Your question with explanation that You've added config and now You have another error.

Comment: thank you @num8er it worked.
now i see in browser "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

Comment: @Mustafajabbar `apt install php8.0-mysqli php8.0-pdo`  and then `systemctl restart php8.0-fpm`

Comment: Still the problem

Comment: @Mustafajabbar have You restarted php fpm after installing mysqli and pdo?

Comment: Yes, but no change

Comment: make `test.php` with: `<?php phpinfo();`  to check list of modules available, make sure in info page You see mysql, mysqli, pdo extension, if not so will need to enable `pdo_mysql.so` in configs

Comment: @Mustafajabbar what, how You fixed?

Comment: There was a problem with the installation of Version
Because the server is old it had to be installed on php7.2 and then php7.4 and now php8.0
Therefore, there may be extra files that were hindering the work
I did purge all Versions and then reinstalled and it worked (as you told me)